# What values to set for Apache 2 worker server pool management?

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, performance, configuration, mpm-worker

I recently switched from Apache 2.2 prefork to Apache 2.2 worker, but I have no idea what would be a great MPM config to start with. On prefork, I used :
MaxClients 256
StartServers 190
MinSpareServers 160
MaxSpareServers 220

I'd like to be able to accept at least as much simultaneous requests (190)

Thanks !

PS: Server environment: Debian 5.0, 2x 3.00 Ghz, 4 GB RAM, dedicated to Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the following settings which are working pretty well :

```
StartServers 8
MaxClients 1024
MinSpareThreads 512
MaxSpareThreads 1024
ThreadsPerChild 64
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
```

I chose greater values since the memory footprint is supposed to be much smaller. I noticed too that when running apachectl configtest (or start/stop) with weird values, it reports the error and auto adjusts the settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
ServerLimit 256
MaxClients 256
StartServers 19
ThreadsPerChild 10
MinSpareThreads 160
MaxSpareThreads 220
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
```

This will:

- Start 190 threads when httpd starts
- Serve up to 256 simultaneous requests
- Ensure a min of 160 spare threads
- Limit a max of 220 spare threads
- Limit each httpd child process to serving 10,000 requests before replacing it with a new child process.  This helps prevent hanging up the apache server in case there are memory leaks in the underlying application.

Comment: I'm no Apache expert, but from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html I take it that "MaxClients 256" limits to 256 threads *in total*. Shouldn't that be higher when a "MinSpareThreads 160" is also enforced. Could your config not be more robust by using fewer parameters and letting Apaches default auto-tuning take care of the rest?

Comment: jesper makes a good point.  The default vaules for those directives are better than what you were using with prefork and the ones I mentioned.  The only directive you might want to use is the 'MinSpareThreads 160' as the default is 10.  Definitely read the link jesper mentioned as well as http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html to help you make the best decision on how to set these directives.

Comment: whoops, the default MinSpareThreads is 75 NOT 10.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I set :
    StartServers          8
    MaxClients         1024
    MinSpareThreads     512
    MaxSpareThreads    1024
    ThreadsPerChild      64
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000

I chose greater values since the memory footprint is supposed to be much smaller. I noticed too that when running apachectl configtest (or start/stop) with weird values, it reports the error and auto adjusts the settings.